# What is the reasoning behind the suggested edit in 'estuve vs estaba: When do I use imperfect versus preterite for "estar"?'

Tags: soporte

There is an *estuve/estaba* question with 13K views, wow! [estuve vs estaba: When do I use imperfect versus preterite for "estar"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12548/1674)

A "community edit" was made to an answer recently, by the mysterious "community," that I can't figure out. The [suggested edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13103) doesn't seem to me to be an improvement over the previous version.

It changes

> Yo cojo el metro [**a diario**, dos veces **por** semana...]

into

> Yo cojo el metro [**cada día**, dos veces **a la** semana...]

The edit I would like to see is to replace "Yo cojo el metro" with "Yo tomo el metro," or at least there should be some note warning people that in some countries *coger* should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was the one who accepted the edit. It is not a great improvement but, to me, it sounds like a good change: both expressions (the original and the final one) are correct, but the second sounds more natural and common to me, here in Spain.

Regarding the edit you would like to see: that's a good one and indeed more important. I just did a [little change in that direction](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/12565/revisions), but feel free to do so.

Posts belong to everyone and once you raise 1000 reputation you have the privilege to [edit questions and answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Since you have such privilege, use it!

Comment: I like the way you handled the coger/tomar problem, thanks. // I still don't see what's wrong with "a diario" (a phrase I personally am very fond of) -- but I guess *cada dia* is okay too....